# Windows 10のIISでPHPを動かす

Tags: php, iis

お世話になります．

Windows 10のIISでPHPを動かしたいです．

PHPそのものはダウンロードして、php-cgi.exeがコマンドラインでエラーなく起動できるところまではできました．

ところが、以前別のテストでIISを有効にして動かしていたのですが、その際にCGIを有効にしていなかったので、それ以上進めることができない状態です．IISへのPHPランタイムの登録でFastCgiModuleを指定しても「そんなモジュールはない」と蹴られます．

どのようにしたらすでにインストール済みのIISでCGIを有効にできるのでしょうか？いろいろWebを見てみたのですが、マッチするページにゆきつけません．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

失礼しました．

自己解決しました．

「コントロール パネル\プログラム\プログラムと機能」で「Windowsの機能の有効化または無効化」で出る「インターネットインフォメーションサービス」で簡単に「CGI」を有効にできました．